# One simple_form_for both New and Edit methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, simple-form-for

Trying to find a way to use one simple_form_for for two functions- new and edit.

`= simple_form_for @news_item, :url => url_for(:action => 'create', :controller => 'news_items'),
    :method => 'post' do |f|
    = f.input :title, input_html: { class: 'title-input' }
    = f.input :contents, input_html: { class: 'contents-input' }
    .actions
      = f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-success'`

Currently, this form will create new form every time hit submit button but can I send this to :url => url_for(:action => 'update') as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
= simple_form_for @news_item, url: (@news_item.new_record? ? news_items_index_path(@news_item) : news_items_path(@news_item)), method: (@news_item.new_record? ? :post : :patch) do |f|
```

Or something like that, you get the picture...

Comment: Thank you so much!! For some reason the line didn't work but this worked: ```= simple_form_for @news_item, :url => @news_item.new_record? ? url_for(action: 'create', controller: 'admin/news_items') : url_for(action: 'update', controller: 'admin/news_items') do |f|```